# Simple search only searching last word of record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search

I set up a simple search as instructed in part of railscast #240.

in controller

```
 @reports = Report.search(params[:search]).order('created_at DESC').paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 5)
```

in model

```
  def self.search(search)
    if search
      where('apparatus LIKE ?', "%#{search}") 
    else
      scoped
    end
  end
```

in view

```
<%= form_tag reports_path, :method => :get do %>
    <p>
        <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
        <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

it all works... but...
I have a few records for example, one with "another time test" and another with "last test of time"
if i search "test" the first comes up but the second doesn't, and if i search "time" the second comes up but not the first. It is only seeing the last word of the record.

what gives?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put a percent sign on both sides of the search term.  Like so:

```
where('apparatus LIKE ?', "%#{search}%")
```

By putting the percent sign before the search term, you're leaving everything before it as a wildcard.  However, you're also saying, by not putting after the search term, that nothing after this should be considered a wildcard.  That's why it only matching the last word.

Comment: that worked, now how would i add searching another field, i tried adding || where('body LIKE ?', "%#{search}%") but that doesn't do anything

Comment: got it: where('apparatus LIKE ? OR body LIKE ?', "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%")